# Nest post request is working in Swagger, but not when I use axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, typeorm, nest

last days I faced problem from title, Its my first post so I will try to explain everything with code snippets to better illustrate the issue.

- Preflight returns code OK 204 no content
- xhr returns error code 500

This is the working swagger request:

```sh
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:3000/activity/createActivity' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "name": "any string",
  "imagePath": "https://www.image.com/image.png",
  "description": "any string",
  "category": 0
}'
```

thats my axios post:

```ts
async addActivity(): Promise<Activity> {
  const activity = await http.post<Activity>("/activity/createActivity", {
    name: "x",
    imagePath: "x",
    description: "x",
    category: 0,
  });
  return activity.data;
}
```

and http:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3000",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
});
```

I guess that I messed something in method above, because Nest returns me this error only when I use addActivity():

> ```
> SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed: activities.name
> QueryFailedError: SQLITE_CONSTRAINT: NOT NULL constraint failed:
> activities.name
>     at Statement.handler (C:\Users\PC0\WebstormProjects\sprogstimulering-backend\src\driver\sqlite\SqliteQueryRunner.ts:113:26)
> ```

- I enabled cors in backend and other requests works,
- `{ name: "x", imagePath: "x", description: "x", category: 0 }` this part in my request is detcted as "data:",
  and I have tried to use `body:{ name: "x", imagePath: "x", description: "x", category: 0 }` but it didnt make any difference,
- no authorisation yet, so its not the problem,

If someone can see mistake or help by providing any good article to the topic. I would be really glad to understand why its acting this way and be smarter in future :/
Thank You in advance!

PS. I have noticed that request header content type is:
"application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json",
and response header is:
"Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: Is `http` an Axios instance? Has it been customised at all with default headers or interceptors?

Comment: Yes, HTTP is an Axios instance with a specified localhost URL and headers. Regarding interceptors, I'm still a little new in this topic and I didn't know about them at all, my bad. I added http code in the post above. Sorry for the lousy formatting I will try to improve in the future.

Comment: Why did you customise the default content-type header? It's completely unnecessary

Comment: Its, because my teacher did that in class, I deleted the header and it works now. Thank You a lot.